# HikariCP throws access denied for user despite the exact same settings as with DBCP and JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, connection-pooling, hikaricp

I am trying to use HikariCP for connection pooling but am getting access denied despite using all the same settings (which I verified) that i used with DBCP and that work with a straight JDBC connection. I cannot figure out why it is denied.

The exception:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'TestUser'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:998)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3835)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3771)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:870)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1659)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1206)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2239)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2270)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2069)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:794)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:44)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:389)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:399)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:325)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource.getConnection(MysqlDataSource.java:422)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource.getConnection(MysqlDataSource.java:134)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.BaseHikariPool.addConnection(BaseHikariPool.java:444)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.BaseHikariPool.initializeConnections(BaseHikariPool.java:548)
        ... 13 more
```

My JDBC URL is: `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/Test` which is 100% correct (including the port).

The only things I set were:

```
    //Start our configuration
    HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();

    //Set the connection settings
    config.setJdbcUrl( "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/Test" );
    config.setUsername( "TestUser" );
    config.setPassword( "test" );

    //Data source class
    config.setDataSourceClassName( "com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource" );

    //Set our settings
    config.addDataSourceProperty( "cachePrepStmts", "true") );
    config.addDataSourceProperty( "prepStmtCacheSize", "250" );
    config.addDataSourceProperty( "prepStmtCacheSqlLimit", "2048" );

    //Create the datasource
    dataSource = new HikariDataSource(config);
```

I'm using Java 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer here: https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/issues/386#issuecomment-132256375

> I will note that you should either use dataSourceClasName and "dataSource." properties (for server, port, etc), **or don't use dataSourceClassName at all and just use the jdbcUrl** (but continue to use "dataSource." properties).

Answer (score 0):

Remove the password field from datasource proprties, the issue you facing because of MySql has not stored any password in its vault but from your code you are trying to make connection with password.